# Stored procedure to add new data to a table that contains foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, foreign-keys

I am working with a couple of stored procedures to add new data into my tables. I have a procedure for my `Customers` table to add new customers, and another procedure for my `Car` table. These work fine since they don't contain foreign keys, however I have a repair services table that has `Customer_ID` and `Car_ID` foreign keys, and I want to be able to reference a car and customer using their keys but I'm not sure how to do it in my stored procedure.

This is my repair service table:

```
  Ticket_ID   TicketNum DateReceived  DateReturned  Car_ID  Customer_ID
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
      1        EDF087   2020-11-10      2020-11-14    6         6
      2        EDF135   2021-03-19      2021-03-25    7         7
      3        EDF235   2020-06-04      2020-06-10    8         8
      4        EDF572   2021-08-09      2021-08-11    9         9
      5        EDF012   2020-04-25      2020-04-26    10        10
```

Now I can add new TicketNum/Dates fine with this, which obviously will just return null values for my foreign keys since I haven't referenced them yet.

```
create procedure TestProcServices
    @TNum varchar(6), 
    @DReceived Datetime, 
    @DReturned Datetime
as
    insert into ServiceTicket2 (TicketNum, DateReceived, DateReturned)
    values (@TNum, @DReceived, @DReturned)

    select scope_identity()

    if @@ERROR != 0 OR @@ROWCOUNT != 1 
    begin
        select ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE() 
        return -1
    end

    return 0



exec TestProcServices 'EDF023', '09/20/2021', '09/22/2021'
```

But I'm wondering where to go from here? Do I have to make an else statement and create the values for each new customer and also for each car inside this one procedure? Or is there a way for me to reference the other tables, since I can create new customers and cars already with my other stored procedures.

Comment: Your stored procedure needs parameters for the car and the customer,be it their IDs directly or some other value such as name / registration (there would need to be some logic in your stored procedure to look up the ids, probably an INSERT INTO.....SELECT FROM)

Comment: If you had to write the process down, in plain english, to explain where the ID values come from, what would you say?

Comment: Why are you using a stored procedure instead of executing an insert statement from your app layer?

Comment: @SEarle1986 Ok did I just overthink this? This seems to be working as I want it     
`create proc TestProcService3
@TNum varchar(6), @DReceived Datetime, @DReturned Datetime, @CarID int, @CustID int
as
    begin
 select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
         insert into ServiceTicket2(TicketNum, DateReceived, DateReturned, Car_ID, Customer_ID)
   values(@TNum, @DReceived, @DReturned, @CarID, @CustID)
      end

exec TestProcService3 'EDF012', '04/20/2021', '04/22/2021', 12, 13`  It will return an error if I enter a car/cust id that doesn't exist, so it seems to be checking the other tables.

Comment: Yes, like that. If you have foreign keys set up, inserting a non existent customer ID or car ID will error. Not sure why you select the scope identity though

Comment: `select SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is bogus there. It should only be used *after* inserting, to get the most recent ID. Why would you `SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE` just let the error bubble back to the client